# UITableView Dynamic Section

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I am using a tableview, which uses dynamic sections, I have an sectionArray which consists of section title and another array which is having the whole data for all sections, 
I could not make it out how to write cell for row for each section as it is dynamic

The code is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [appDelegate.sectionArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [appDelegate.appNameArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  UILabel *AppNameLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 120, 30)];
  [AppNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [AppNameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.appNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
  [AppNameLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:AppNameLabel];
  return cell;
}
```

In appname array I have data consisting for all sections, I need to segregate for particular section , how to make it in cell for row index pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create two different `array` for sectionTitle and appName. Create source `NSArray` with `NSDictionary` of objects. `NSDictionary` object contains the appName array as `values` and sectionTitle as `key`.

```
sourceArray
(
 dictionaryObject1
 {
 key : sectionTitle,
 value : ( appName1,appName2,appName3)
 },
 dictionaryObject2
 {
 key : sectionTitle,
 value : ( appName1,appName2,appName3)
 },
.
.
.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `numberOfRowsInSection` method should look something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *arrayForSection = appDelegate.sectionArray[section];
    return [arrayForSection count];
}
```

After that modify the `cellForRow` method:

```
NSArray *arrayForSection = appDelegate.sectionArray[indexPath.section]
[AppNameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayForSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: How it will diffrentiate according to the sections? i mean, i get section array as my dates(september 12) and in appnamearray contains 2013-09-12 13:07:03 Appname,2013-09-11 13:07:03 Appname,2013-09-10 13:07:03 Appname etc.... how it will assign according to the section names?

Comment: Well you will need to work on the way you use data structures. You need to have one main array(for the sections) and it will be filled with other arrays - one for each section, containing information for the rows in that section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your datasource accordingly. Just edit your array dynamically by enumerating your array. Like if you have added a section then you should add section detail in your array dynamically.

```
NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray alloc] initWithArray:sectionArray];
for(int i = index; i<= (sectionArray.count-i-1); i++)
{
   if(i = index){
      [sectionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newSection]
   }
   else
   {
     sectionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex: i-1];
   }
}
```

Comment: wre sholud i implement this in my cell for row or number of sections ?

Comment: I have just given you the idea.. this code will update your sectionArray and if you want to distinguish the rows of different section then you should make an array of dictionaries with section names and then individual dictionary containing array of each section.